# Get which Jframe opened another Jframe

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

Say I have a `JFrame` called `childJframe`.

If I create a new childJFrame from two different `JFrame`s. How can I get which particular JFrame created the childJFrame.

Thus:

```
public class myPage1 extends javax.swing.JFrame{
    // on a Button clicked
    childJFrame cjf = new childJFrame();
    cjf.setVisible(true);
}
```

And the Second class is

```
public class myPage2 extends javax.swing.JFrame{
    // on a Button clicked
    childJFrame cjf = new childJFrame();
    cjf.setVisible(true);
}
```

How can I find out if `cjf` is an instance of `myPage1` or `myPage2`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Window class, which JFrame descends from, has a `getOwner()` method that will return the "owner" Window for any child windows.

But having said that, child windows should be JDialogs, **not** JFrames as your application should have one and only one JFrame, and I believe that JFrames don't have owners, so that this method may return null. If you need to change "views" within the JFrame, use a CardLayout, and if you need to display child windows, use dialog windows such as JDialogs and JOptionPanes. Please read: [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636), for more on this.

But having said this, I do have to wonder if your question may in fact be an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) where you ask "how do I fix this code" when the real solution is to use a different (read -- more "object oriented") approach entirely.

Answer (score 3):

If your child windows must really be `JFrame` instances (I suppose `ChildJFrame` extends `JFrame`), I think the simplest solution consists in keeping track of the parent `JFrame` in the `ChildJFrame` instance. Since `ChildJFrame` is a custom class of yours, this is easy:

- Add a `JFrame` (or `Frame` or `Window`) attribute to your `ChildJFrame` class;
- Add to `ChildJFrame` a constructor that takes a parameter that will be assigned to the above attribute;
- When you create a `ChildJFrame` instance from one of your `JFrame`-derived classes, just add `this` as a parameter.

Then you have everything you need to interact with the parent `JFrame`.